# schedule job in ssms from remote server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to schedule the code below with ssms using the sql server agent jobs. It does not seem to want to run though and in the job activity monitor it says 'never' for last run. I am on server "A" and the database is on server "B". I can run code and update from ssms on "A" but when I check the sql server config manager on the pc on server "A" it shows they are all stopped. On "B" they are all running. I tried to start them manually but get the error below. Is there something I need to do to be able to schedule on the remote server? Thanks.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [DE_ID].[DBO].[tte]
(
[NEW_F_NUM] [int] Not Null,
[F_DESCRIPTION] [varchar](50) NULL
)
            
BULK INSERT DE_ID.DBO.tte FROM 'C:\SQL\TABLES\tte.txt'
    WITH (FIRSTROW = 2);
```

Comment: You can't start SQL Server Agent when the SQL Server Data Engine isn't running...

Comment: How do i get it to run on the different server?

Comment: You don't, Agent runs off the local instance.

Comment: Well shoot. Thank you for the info.Much appreciated.

Comment: SQL agent and SQL server must be on the same machine as each other. You can connect to them from elsewhere but that's how you need to install it